# TestWindow: How to fire a global event, like "window:keydown"

Tags: stenciljs

I'm writing a test for a component that listens to "window:keydown".
I've tried several methods, but none of them works:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new testWindow.Event("window:keydown"))
window.dispatchEvent(new testWindow.Event("window:keydown"))
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("keydown"))
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("window:keydown"))
```

What is the correct syntax instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
const keyCode = 37; // Left, but can be done wherever
const keyboardOptions: any = { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode };
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", keyboardOptions));
```

See https://github.com/mattdsteele/joy-con-element/blob/master/src/components/joy-con/joy-con.tsx#L65 for a more detailed example.